# Calculate time difference between rows with specific values

Tags: mysql

I have a table tracking the status of devices:

```
StatusId       DeviceId       DeviceStatus       StatusTimestamp
1              device1        Available          2021-05-18 10:14:13.669
2              device1        Error              2021-05-20 14:57:55.850
3              device1        Available          2021-05-20 15:02:12.421
4              device1        Error              2021-05-23 11:12:43.839
5              device1        Available          2021-05-23 11:14:16.192
...
```

Now I need to get the time a device was in "Error" status for a specific month. I am wondering if I can calculate this time within a single query. So for this example this would be:

Sum([ROW5 - ROW4], [ROW3 - ROW2])

Is there a way to solve this with a single query? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the LAG() function, which basically offsets the rows by one. So you make something like:

```
SELECT status, timestap - LAG(timestamp)
FROM health
```

You will have to modify the query to get only the diffs from errors and then sum them all up.